# python count of the recursive calls to function

Tags: python, recursion

The amount of recursive calls to the following function need to be counted:

```
def fb(n, d):
    if n in d:
        return d[n]
    else:
        ans = fb(n-1, d) + fb(n-2, d)
        d[n] = ans
        return ans
d = {1:1, 2:2}
print(fb(8, d))
print(d)
```

Now i understand the function, and what essentially happens, i just cant wrap my brain around counting the amount of recursions manually(by hand). I can count the recursions with code  or jsut by looking at 'd' but im unable to understand why there are only 13 recursive calls in the end.

The following happens in my mind:
ans makes 2 recursive calls (n = 7 and n = 6) each of these two make two more calls etc etc till all these calls end with an n of 2 or 1.

But if i look at the code, and just print the n on every time the function is run i get the following output:

```
def fb(n, d):
    if n in d:
        return d[n]
    else:
        print(n)
        ans = fb(n-1, d) + fb(n-2, d)
        d[n] = ans
        return ans
d = {1:1, 2:2}
print(fb(8, d))
```

Output:

```
8
7
6
5
4
3
32
```

Now i know the answer is 13, 2 calls to the function (2 * 6) on each number + the last call which returns the ans. But my question is, how is this internally working, and how can i replicate this thought process in my head.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try to see it run here - https://pythontutor.com/   if you don't want to use *decorator* way

Comment: It's interesting to note that without the memoization (that is, comment out the `d[n] = ans` step), you get 41 calls to the function.

Comment: I think what stumped you is that you thought (as I did!) that both calls to fb(n-1) and fb(n-2) were performed in parallel; that's not the case: the "left path" is executed completely first.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you to understand it:

```
def fb(n, d, indent):
    if n in d:
        print(indent, n, "old")
        return d[n]
    else:
        print(indent, n, "new")
        indent2 = indent + "  "
        ans = fb(n-1, d, indent2) + fb(n-2, d, indent2)
        d[n] = ans
        return ans
d = {1:1, 2:2}
print(fb(8, d, ""))
```

I augmented the function in two different ways:  (1) I show all calls, whether the value is old or new, and (2) I indent based on the call depth.  The results are:

```
 8 new
   7 new
     6 new
       5 new
         4 new
           3 new
             2 old
             1 old
           2 old
         3 old
       4 old
     5 old
   6 old
34
```

As you can see, it starts with a chain of recursive calls with `n-1`, getting new values until it reaches 2.  At that point, it's an old value, so it returns immediately.

The caller then makes a recursive call with `n-2` (i.e. 1).  This is the first time the `n-2` call has been executed.  And of course, it too is an old value so it returns immediately.  The caller then adds the two, stores the result (for 3), and returns.  This is the first time a new case has returned.

It then just repeats, but now all of the `n-2` calls are old calls.  When it reaches the top level, it adds the results for 7 and 6 to obtain the value for 8, and returns to the top-level caller, giving a result of 34.

Answer (score 1):

> The following happens in my mind: ans makes 2 recursive calls (n = 7 and n = 6) each of these two make two more calls etc etc till all these calls end with an n of 2 or 1.

You need to be more strict about your logic here. First of all `ans` is a variable. So saying "ans makes 2 recursive calls" is nonsense. Also, the line with the recursive calls is inside the `else` block of an `if` statement, so you need to evaluate the condition of the `if` to determine whether or not a recursive call even happens.

So let's analyze this more thoroughly for `fib(7)`. Since `7` is not a key in the dictionary, we make a recursive call to `fib(6)`. This in turn calls `fib(5)` and so on until we get to `fib(2)`. Let's represent each recursive call with indentation:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4)
        fib(3)
          fib(2)
```

Now we get to a point where the `if` condition is `True` because the dictionary has `2` as a key. So and `fib(2)` returns `2`. Let's note that with `->`

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4)
        fib(3)
          fib(2) -> 2
```

Now `fib(3)` calls `fib(n - 2)` which is `fib(1)`. And `fib(1)` returns `1`. We just add this with the appropriate level of indentation:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4)
        fib(3)
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
```

Now `fib(3)` adds the result of `2 + 1` to the dictionary and returns:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4)
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
```

Now we are at the `fib(4)` level, which calls `fib(2)` and which returns `2`:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4)
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
```

And now `fib(4)` returns `3 + 2`:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4) -> 5
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
```

Now we are back at the `fib(5)` call which calls `fib(n - 2)` or `fib(3)`:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4) -> 5
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
       fib(3)
```

But we already called `fib(3)` and stored its value in the dictionary. So this returns immediately without any additional recursive calls:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5)
      fib(4) -> 5
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
       fib(3) -> 3
```

And now `fib(5)` returns `5 + 3`:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5) -> 8
      fib(4) -> 5
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
       fib(3) -> 3
```

Now we are back at `fib(6)` which calls `fib(4)`. Again, we have already calculated this and its result is returned immediately:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6)
    fib(5) -> 8
      fib(4) -> 5
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
       fib(3) -> 3
    fib(4) -> 5
```

Now `fib(6)` returns `5 + 8`:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6) -> 13
    fib(5) -> 8
      fib(4) -> 5
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
       fib(3) -> 3
    fib(4) -> 5
```

And we are back at `fib(7)` which calls `fib(5)` next. Again, we have already calculated this value and stored it, so we return immediately:

```
fib(7)
  fib(6) -> 13
    fib(5) -> 8
      fib(4) -> 5
        fib(3) -> 3
          fib(2) -> 2
          fib(1) -> 1
         fib(2) -> 2
       fib(3) -> 3
    fib(4) -> 5
  fib(5) -> 8
```

And finally `fib(7)` returns `13 + 8` or `21`.

As you can see there are `11` recursive calls for `fib(7)`. I let you do the rest of the analysis for `fib(8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the calls, in a tree shape (only the value of n is shown, with calls where n is already in d in parenthesis):

```
                                 8
                                / \
                               7  (6)
                              / \
                             6  (5)
                            / \
                           5  (4)
                          / \
                         4  (3)
                        / \
                       3  (2)
                      / \
                    (2) (1)
```

First the left side of the tree if traveled, then you get up the right side.
Hoping it helps you see it more clearly (I know it DOES for me!).